# How to get CDF from PDF

Tags: probability, functions

How can I get CDF from this PDF:
[image: Probability distribution function.]
Mine solution is: [image: solution], but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed: $$\int_{x_m}^x \alpha x_m^\alpha s^{-1-\alpha}\mathbf 1_{s>x_m}\operatorname d s = (1- x_m^\alpha x^{-\alpha})\mathbf 1_{x>x_m}$$

Your answer was mostly okay, but missed noting the support for the random variable.